# What happens if I use both jokers in a hand?

Tags: deadlands-reloaded

What happens if a player is making a poker hand and draws both jokers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Dealing with the Devil, using a Joker in the eventual hand you make means you roll on the Backfire Table in the Marshal's Handbook. If you have two Jokers in your hand you roll twice, the effects being cumulative.

For example, if you result of the two rolls are both Brain Drain, the Huckster would take a wound, as he is first Shaken, then immediately Shaken again. If two separate Dementia rolls were made, I would roll that you could take two minor dementias or one major one.